# finding a confusing limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

yeah just another limit.
I have

$Xn=\dfrac{1000^n}{\sqrt{n!}} + 1$

that $+1$ confuses me

any hints & solutions how to calculate limit will be apreciated

Comment: The $+1$ is in the denominator? Or outside the fraction? And I suppose $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: post edited @Ludolila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, you could use $$X_n-1=\dfrac{1000^n}{\sqrt{n!}}$$ Take the logarithms $$\log(X_n-1)=n \log(10000)-\frac{1}{2} \log(n!)$$ and use Stirling approximation which is $$\log(n!)=n \log(n)-n+\frac{1}{2}\log(2 n\pi)$$ Replacing, it is easy to notice that $\log(X_n-1)$ goes to $-\infty$ and so ... the answers you already received.

Answer (score 3):

$\dfrac{1000^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\rightarrow_{\infty}0$  because $(\dfrac{a^n}{n!^b})\rightarrow_{\infty}0$ for $a,b>0$

Therefore $\dfrac{1000^n}{\sqrt{n!}}+1\rightarrow_{\infty}1$

Comment: I solved this limit in a same way, but my teacher says that it is not enough and you have to use monotone of sequence..

Comment: @user2965303 What exactly is not enough according to your professor ? Where's the problem in the logic?

Answer (score 1):

For $n \gt 4000000$ you have $\frac{1000}{\sqrt{n}}\lt \frac12$

but $\dfrac{ X_{n}-1}{X_{n-1}-1} = \dfrac{\frac{1000^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}} }{\frac{1000^{n-1}}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}} } = \dfrac{1000}{\sqrt{n}}$

so $0 \lt X_{n}-1 \lt \frac{1}{2}\left(X_{n-1}-1\right)$

implying $\displaystyle X_n-1\to 0$ and $\displaystyle X_n\to 1$.

Comment: I think you misread the question. It's $\sqrt{n!}$, not $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @rubik: Yes, so  $\dfrac{ X_{n}-1}{X_{n-1}-1} = \dfrac{\frac{1000^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}} }{\frac{1000^{n-1}}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}} } = \dfrac{1000}{\sqrt{n}}\lt \dfrac12$

Comment: Oh yes, the error was on my part. Thanks for clarifying!